Can I add tags to mobs with specific NBT
I know how to add tags to mobs through datapacks, but the .json files use mob ids to select which mobs to give them to. Can I give tags to mobs with a specific NBT as well? For example, giving a tag to all mobs with onGround:1 NBT.

Tags only group resource locations together, and cannot account for NBT data. If you want to target all entities with the OnGround tag set, you'll need to find another method to do so.
Selectors allow you to specify NBT with the nbt property of the selector.
For example: @e[nbt={OnGround:true}]

Assumed there wasn't a way. Sadly I need it to add a tag added by a mod to specific mobs, so that won't be possible then.
